# Android: Redundancy in the DB or runtime computation?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, redundancy

I noticed that there are some related questions, but haven't found any related specifically to Android.

I'm building an Android app and in developing my database schema, I'm unsure if I should store some data in the DB and update it after each relevant change or keep redundancy at a minimum and compute the data realtime.

Which option is better for an Android app?

One small example: An app with categories and items. The items have certain points that add up if they are part of a category. Should the total sum per category be computed realtime from all assigned items or be stored in the category table and updated with each insert/deletion of an item?

Comment: That depends on the size of your table and how often you will update it vs. how often you will read the aggregate.

Comment: **updated with each insert/deletion of an item** I would prefer this in case of only insertion or deletion. But in apps, this is just hypothetical cases, there might be multiple updates from multiple sources referring same object. Yea, this question is too broad, so answers will also be broad.

Answer (score 1):

The question *Is it worth?* fully depends on the database usage.

Think about these points below to decide what you should do.

If the computations are long, it could be worth saving them for later reading.

- How much reading do you perform? How often?

If the computations are short, the computations are so small you won't even notice.

- How hard is it to calculate the sum? Is calculating it each time computationally expensive?

In mobile apps, it's not usual to have big amounts of data, for obvious reasons, a database doesn't usually reach millions, what in servers is common.

You could provide some more details so that we can guide you better.